# Page refresh displays entire localstorage object

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have built a todo list using Vanilla Javascript and localstorage.  The todo list has the following key, value:

```
key: todolist
value: [[\"id:0\",\"title:buy groceries\",\"done:false\"], 
[\"id:1\",\"title:pick up dry cleaning\",\"done:false\"], 
[\"id:2\",\"title:walk dog\",\"done:false\"]]
```

The values display just great on my website (only the title is displaying) but when I refresh the page, the whole object is displaying.

Before page refresh:

buy groceries

pick up dry cleaning

walk dog

After page refresh:

id:0,title:buy groceries,done:false

id:1,title:pick up dry cleaning,done:false

id:2,title:walk dog,done:false

Obviously, after a page refresh I only want the title to display on the list inside the li tag.  It's a head scratcher because it only does this after a page refresh.

How do I get only the title to display after page refresh?

I'm somewhat of a newbie to Javascript and can't quite figure out how to make this happen.  I've been Googling for almost two days and ready to tear my hair out!!

```
// set up some variables for elements on the page
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.getElementById('item');


// Fix empty array when script runs by making a conditional statement that 
checks if localStorage already exists

//let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('todolist') ? 
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todolist')) : [];

let todolist;

if (localStorage.getItem('todolist')) {
itemsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todolist'));
} else {
itemsArray = [];
}

localStorage.setItem('todolist', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todolist'));

//alert(typeof(data));




// function that creates an li element, sets the text of the element to the 
parameter, and appends the list item to the ul.
const liMaker = (text) => {
const li = document.createElement('li');
li.textContent = text;
ul.appendChild(li);


// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
 var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
var txt = document.createTextNode("️");

span.className = "close";
span.appendChild(txt);
li.appendChild(span);

for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
close[i].onclick = function() {
var div = this.parentElement;
div.style.display = "none";
}
}
}


// Event listener that submits the value of the input 
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var id = "id:" + itemsArray.length;
var title = "title:" + input.value;
var done = "done:" + "false";

itemsArray.push([id, title, done]);
//itemsArray.push(input.value);
localStorage.setItem('todolist', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
liMaker(input.value);
input.value = ""; 
});

data.forEach(item => {
liMaker(item);
});

// clear items from todolist
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
localStorage.removeItem("todolist");
while (ul.firstChild) {
ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
}
itemsArray = [];
});
```

One thing I should note, the page refresh issue doesn't happen when I change the following:
    itemsArray.push([id, title, done]);
to the following:
    itemsArray.push(input.value);

Comment: can you post properly indented code with your html. probably you should create a code snippet with html and js. then everyone can take a look. its really hard to tell from this. But I  think your issue might have to do something with the way you saving your value object.

Comment: Where it says data.foreach (item => { liMaker (item); }); should that not be liMaker(item.title); ?

Comment: liMaker(item) is putting the whole object as the text of the list item instead of just the title so i think if u change it to liMaker(item.title) it will work

Comment: Hey @sjackson . I wrote an answer for you which i've also just updated to explain about the page refresh. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give it a shot.  I'm not sure what happened with the comments and indenting...next time I'll put everything into a jsfiddle.  I'll let you know if your suggestion works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason you are having this problem is because your JSON is not formatted properly.
The reason you are only seeing the problem on page refresh is because at this point local storage contains the "`todolist`" key with your improperly formed JSON. This JSON value is then stored in your `data` variable and output to your list items in an undesired way (as you described).

Otherwise (without page refresh) the text of your list items is coming directly from the text in the input field.

If you make the following changes to your code it will work properly (I have tested it). Hope it helps.

## JavaScript comments

Firstly i'm not sure if this just happened when you posted your code here but if your comments in JS extend across two lines or more then you need to put `//` on all lines.

For example in your code you have:

```
//function that creates an li element, sets the text of the element to the 
parameter, and appends the list item to the ul.
```

and it should be:

```
//function that creates an li element, sets the text of the element to the 
//parameter, and appends the list item to the ul.
```

## The format of your JSON

Secondly I see a problem with the way the JSON is formatted. 
It should look something like the following (before slashes are added).

```
[{"id":0,"title":"buy groceries","done":false}, 
{"id":1,"title":"pick up dry cleaning","done":false}, 
{"id":2,"title":"walk dog","done":false}]
```

Note each property name (i.e `"id"`, `"title"` and `"done"`) should have double quotes and each property value (e.g `"buy groceries"`) should have double quotes (unless its an int or a boolean etc).
You can use a tool called [JSLint](https://www.jslint.com/) to check your JSON is valid.

So in order to create your JSON in the right format (when the form is submitted)

change these lines of code:

```
var id = "id:" + itemsArray.length;
var title = "title:" + input.value;
var done = "done:" + "false";
itemsArray.push([id, title, done]);
```

to the following:

```
var idValue = itemsArray.length;
var titleValue = input.value;
var doneValue = false;
itemsArray.push({"id": idValue, "title": titleValue, "done" : doneValue});
```

## Iterating through the array

Your `data` variable will contain the array of todolist objects (from local storage).

So therefore the `item` you have in the following code will contain the full object i.e `{"id":0,"title":"buy groceries","done":false}`.

So in order to get the title here you need to say `item.title`. (This will work now that the JSON will be properly formatted):

```
  data.forEach(item => {
    //log the item to check it.
    console.log(item);
    liMaker(item.title);
  });
```

Comment: Yessss!! This is the answer I needed :)  Next time I will create a jsfiddle.  Thank you, thank you!!

Comment: @sjackson That's great! No probs :)